# passing information in an form? confused with some of the examples on SO

Tags: html, forms

I need to pass this so a hardware engineer can do his work but it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=3&cmd=replace&text="
```

Here is my code...

```
 <div class="messageform">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Title 1</legend> 
 <form action=http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi?msg=1&cmd=replace&text=" method="post">
 <label for="mestext1"></label>
 <input type="text" size="100" maxlength="80">
 <div class="floatright">Titles can be up to 80 Characters... upload file if beyond 80 chars &nbsp<input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace"></div><br>
```

I thought I was good on this code but it's not working right, any ideas? Did I miss something?

Comment: In short: you need to send a GET request but you hard-code data in the URL of a POST form and you add additional unnamed form fields that won't be sent.

Comment: `text=doublequote`? That's not a valid url. not when you shove it directly into a form tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better like this:

```
<div class="messageform">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Title 1</legend> 
    <form action="http://wfbscd13.cadence.com/cgi-bin/motd.cgi" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="msg" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="replace"> 
      <label for="mestext1"></label>
      <input type="text" id="mestext1"" name="text" size="100" maxlength="80">
      <div class="floatright">Titles can be up to 80 Characters... upload file if beyond 80 chars
          <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Replace">
      </div>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

You need to be more careful with closing quotes and tags.

If a URL has a '?' in it, it probably means they want it as a GET not a POST.

Use hidden variables for the fixed params.

Don't repeat the `text` param.

The `for` of a `<label>` needs to point to the `id` of a tag.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire code, then its not working probably because the code is not well-formed , i.e. there are places where you have missed to close the tags.

Comment: Don't you think that this rather be a comment since it doesn't provide an answer?